# SAS alternative for MAC

Tags: macos, sas

Can you recommend me any SAS alternatives for Mac? I would not use any Parallel like solution. Which andvantage Oracle technology has in front of SAS?

Comment: This is probably a better question for Superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with SAS already, there is [JMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_(statistical_software)) - it's developed by SAS and runs on the Windows, Mac, and Linux platforms.

Comment: Thanks, I begin to download. I am gettig to know with SAS. JMP is able to do the same as SAS?

Comment: I don't know JMP myself too well, but if your use of SAS is typically in the SAS/STAT or ETS areas, I expect that JMP would likely fit your needs.

Comment: I see, JMP can do the same as SAS, but need a connection to a SAS server, there is no stand alone SAS server inside JMP.

Comment: My understanding is that JMP isn't as powerful as SAS, but if you're doing basic analyses it doesn't matter. Where you'll run into issues is if you want to write macros or run simulations, which JMP wasn't designed for.

Answer (score 1):

WPS works with the SAS language and does much of what base SAS does.  It doesn't have a GUI on the mac (yet) but it will run scripts of SAS code from thus command line.  Most 9.2 syntax is supported including macros.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully run SAS University Edition in my Mac. In the background it runs a VMWare Machine, and I connect to it using SAS Studio in Safari. If you prefer not to do the calculations on your Mac at all it is possible to have VM run in a free-Tier Amazon AWS Machine, thus you don't need to install anything at all on your Mac.

More info on the official [SAS® University Edition](http://www.sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition.html) website.

Answer (score 0):

You can open SAS datasets if they have been exported as transport datasets.
This takes a 4 line SAS program to do, so it is not hard.

You can set up the SAS server in a parallels/VMware machine on the same Mac (I am planning to do this soon, I have seen a set up like this running, so it does work ;-)

From the Stats POV there is little JMP cannot do - what is missing is specialized (eg proc genetics is not available on JMP).

From a data exploration POV JMP is much better than SAS and has many features SAS does not have - principally dynamic selection of observations (often called brushing). It does also do data manipulation - joins, transpose, etc, simply and well.

The latest JMP can call R programs so if you are avoiding SAS because of fees then that is a way to go.

Oracle is a whole other story more focused on databases and applications built on them. SAS is built in the other direction from the reporting down to the data.

HTH